# Azure Purview scan of cosmos database to discover data assets fails sometimes

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-purview

I tested setup Azure Purview and CosmosDB with Provisioned throughput capacity/ serverless capacity mode SQL API with few collections. After Cosmos Data source registration, I initiated scan and provided key vault with secret pointing to CosmosDB account key.
For CosmosDB with Provisioned throughput capacity mode, data assets were discovered successfully.

For capacity mode - serverless CosmosDB SQL API, collection items were not identified as data assets after scan completion.

Comment: You mean that after completing scan, you got wrong results but with no error? Could you please add more details about your action?

Comment: Hi Tiny-wa, I have added snapshot of steps followed, still I do not see assets identified after successful scan with no error

Comment: Hi man, I'm sorry for haven't got any progress in this case. I followed the tutorial to create purview account and connect to key vault, execute a scan, but I can got correct response. I also tried to remove  purview data source admin role but it worked well, and when I use a wrong primary key from cosmosdb, it will fail to connect, so I have no other ideas on it. My suggestion is you may create another cosmosdb and try the scan flow again.

Comment: Hi Tiny-wa, Yes I can with another cosmosdb account. Were collection data assets discovered in your case. I believe yes and I can give try.

Comment: Yes, after the scan executed, I can see 'Assets classified' and 'Assets discovered' with correct count.

Comment: Hi Tiny-wa, it works for cosmosdb capacity mode- Provisioned throughput and did not work for CosmosDB serverless capacity mode. Thanks for help. I have updated question accordingly.

Comment: It's better to make your updating as an answer, and you can mark it as the answer so that will help others.

Comment: Done, Thanks Tiny-wa.

Comment: @akshatthakar You should post an answer( I help you post it), not edit your question. If you want to post it by yourself, I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CosmosDB with Provisioned throughput capacity mode, data assets were discovered successfully.

For capacity mode - serverless CosmosDB SQL API, collection items were not identified as data assets after scan completion.